# get the average of data in sqlite android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I wanted the following query to be executed,

```
  String selectQuery = "SELECT  max(score),name FROM " + TABLE_SCORE
                        +" group by name";
```

I get my output as random values. Actually I wanted the data from the maximum values to the least. Please let me know, how to write the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually I wanted the data from the maximum values to the least

You mean order by max to min value? Try this:

```
  SELECT SUM(score), name 
    FROM MyTable
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/4b8f0/2)

So your query should be like this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT SUM(score), name FROM " + TABLE_SCORE
                        +" GROUP BY name ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC";
```

Comment: @hd1 - OP can't upvote right now :). And always use `@username` to [reply particular user](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). :)

Comment: hey no its not accepting immediately. It told wait for 5 minutes. That's why i waited and voted up.

Comment: @PavithraMohan - Don't worry. That's the rule. No need to accept immediately. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  score, name FROM " + TABLE_SCORE
                        +" order by score, group by name";
```

This will give you the records according to the scores(Ascending order of score).

Comment: No, i am getting error when i run this query,05-06 05:03:02.983: E/AndroidRuntime(7354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newandroid/com.example.newandroid.webview}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "group": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  max(score),name FROM score order by score group by name